# Excepting out of a jboss process when an error case detected

Tags: jboss

Is it possible to throw an exception from JBOSS which will terminate the process? I don't want to do something as crude as system.exit but the code our code runs as a plugin in a larger infrastructure and I want to check some states at startup and exit out of the system if data is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably message to use the [`ModelControllerClient`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/The+native+management+API#ThenativemanagementAPI-Workingwitha%7B%7BModelControllerClient%7D%7D) to connect to the server and execute the `:shutdown` command.

Something like:

```
final ModelControllerClient client = createClient();
try {
    final ModelNode op = new ModelNode();
    op.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(":shutdown");
    op.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).setEmptyList();
    final ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
    if (result.get(ClientConstants.OUTCOME).asString().equals(ClientConstants.SUCCESS)) {
        // Do some there
} finally {
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    } 
}
```

If you're just shutting down you could probably ignore the outcome.